# Div Text not showing

Tags: javascript, css, html, text

This code is meant to display items items as a list in the div above the button but, although the button and prompt work, there is no text displayed in the div. Help!

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Shopping List</title>
        <style>
            #button {
                width:80px;
                height:30px;
            }
            div.ex {
                width:500;
                height:500;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            function a() {
                var thing = prompt('Insert an item or press cancel');

                if (thing != null && thing != undefined) {
                    document.getElementById('b') += thing;
                }
                else {
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class='ex' style="color:#007AFC"></div>
        <button onclick='a()' id='button'>Add Item</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have no text in your div

Comment: do u want that when u give some text in the promt it will apear in the div text ...?

Comment: and no background color... so decide: content and/or background color. if you want content, be sure that the function does work correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you are using `document.getElementById('b')` however you don't have an HTML element with `id="b"`. Secondly, you can't change the HTML content of an element using only the `+=` operator. You need to modify the `innerHTML` attribute like so:

```
 document.getElementById('b').innerHTML += thing;
```

Also, you need to have an HTML element with `id="b"` like so:

```
 <div id="b" class='ex' style="color:#007AFC"></div>
```

However, consider using a more descriptive name for the `id`.

Comment: You amazingly helpful person. Thank You! I should've remembered my.innerHTML suffix :)

Comment: No problem. Vanilla JS can be a bit verbose at times.

Answer (score 0):

Can you really add text with "+="!? I would try it using [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

And what sushain97 says: add a id to the element (id="b"). But if you want to add more items one after the other you need to use append(), not innerHTML(), because innerHTML() will replace all of the content.

Comment: is this your answer ? not jquery usage here( append() )

Comment: Please don't introduce jQuery unless (1) the answer would be much easier using it or (2) the questioner is already using it. There's no purpose to adding a library for something this basic.

Answer (score 0):

html :

```
<div class='ex' style="color:#007AFC" id="b"></div>
```

js:

```
document.getElementById('b').innerHTML+=thing;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mathieujonson/gAPg5/) that shows it working.  The relevant javascript is as follows:

```
document.getElementById('addButton').addEventListener("click", addListItem, false);

function addListItem(){
    var thing=prompt('Insert an item or press cancel') + "<br />";
    if(thing!=null&&thing!=undefined){
        document.getElementById('listDiv').innerHTML += thing;
    }
}
```

Side note:  Try to stay away from inline styles and scripting.  It makes it more difficult to maintain.